# php form not organizing data correctly

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

The form data is being sent to my table correctly but is not being sorted correctly. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Picture of my table problem]

name, email, and message should all have the same ID and stay in the same row. How do I fix this?

code:

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name) VALUES ('$name')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (email) VALUES ('$email')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


$messgae = $_POST['message'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (message) VALUES ('$message')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: what does the code look like?

Comment: !(a picture is worth a thousand words) = please include some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving multiple records at a time to the database, the one you save first gets added first to the table . So arrange the name 1st key in the name attributes to have the records saved in order of precedence.

Edit- code as needed

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name,email,message) VALUES ('$name','$email','$message')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Okay, so would I add this code to the script that saves to the table? Or to the code of the table itself?

Comment: nothing lke that just define the name attributes in the order of name="rec[0]['name']" then on the server side run a loop on that array accordingly.

Comment: Got your point in terms of what you need, use the code I have edited above and it will work fine. Mark this as the answer if correct